# Getting the list out of the recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

The temp in base case is the answer i need.It should be  to be appended to the final.But I am ending up with list of empty lists.Any suggestion?

```
def recur(st,end,a,temp,k,final):
    if sum(temp) == k:
        final.append(temp)
        print(temp)
        return
    if sum(temp)>k:
        return
    if st==end-1:
        return
    st+=1
    temp.append(a[st])
    recur(st,end,a,temp,k,final)
    temp.pop()
    recur(st,end,a,temp,k,final)
for _ in range(int(input())):
    a = list(map(int,input().split()))
    k = int(input())
    a.sort()
    final = []
    temp = []
    recur(-1,len(a),a,temp,k,final)
    print(final)
```

Comment: As written, it's very difficult to understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you provide some context? As a general practice, naming variables as letters makes it a bit less readable. The split in the variable _a_ doesn't really make sense as it will always just return the number entered (and if anything other than a number is entered will return an error). At the very least, I can confirm that it only returns an empty list.

Comment: This is a backtracking problem and the answer should be the list of all combinations that sums to the target in sorted order.Everytime when the base case is executed the temp variable will contain one combination in list.And all i need is to the extract that list out of the function for everytime tha base case is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am ending up with list of empty lists.

That is likely due to this statement:

```
final.append(temp)
```

You're appending the list `temp` to `final` but `temp` will continue to change after this happens and `final` will eventually contain one or more pointers to the *last* value of `temp`, not it's value when you appended it.  To get that, you need to append a *copy* of `temp` that won't change:

```
final.append(list(temp))  # make a copy and stash it away
```

Generally, I agree with @patmcb regarding our inability to guess what this code is trying to do.  However, structurally, I'd expect a properly designed recursive function to look more like:

```
def recur(start, end, array, temp, target):
    total = sum(temp)

    if total == target:
        return [list(temp)]  # a list containing a copy of temp

    if total > target or start == end - 1:
        return []

    start += 1
    temp.append(array[start])
    result = recur(start, end, array, temp, target)
    temp.pop()

    return result + recur(start, end, array, temp, target)

for _ in range(int(input())):
    a = sorted(map(int, input().split()))
    k = int(input())

    print(recur(-1, len(a), a, [], k))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
1
5 10 13 2 4 6
21 
[[2, 4, 5, 10], [2, 6, 13], [5, 6, 10]]
>
```

Comment: Yeah well structured.But what is need is to get all the possible combinations out of the function.This code will stop executing when one combination is found.

Comment: @akashmohan, now that we know what your program is supposed to do, it's a simple modification of the well structured code to get out the desired result.  See updated answer.

Comment: This is what is need bro.But my doubt is,since temp is a array why it is not getting added to the final array when i tried to append.Could you explain me clearly?